# Rewrite raw json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I convert the given code/text into PHP? What would be the PHP syntax of it? There are like some arrays and some objects like items. I would like to restructure it into PHP and be able to convert back to it's original format if necessary.

```
{
  "status": "Pending",
  "client": "John",
  "invoice": {
    "series": "INV",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "total": 20,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 5478,
        "name": "Adapter Lenovo",
        "amount": 1,
        "cost": 10,
      }
    ]
  },
  "parcels": [
    {
      "quantity": "1",
      "weight": 2000
    }
  ],
  "sender": {
    "company": "string",
    "address": {
      "city": "Tallin",
      "street": "New Street"
    }
  },
  "recipient": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "phone": 30258554455
  }
}
```

Comment: `$arr = json_decode( $json_string, true );` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Nothing happens. Just a blank page. $arr is empty. Would you provide the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string into a an array or object using `json_decode()`

```
$json_string = '{
  "status": "Pending",
  "client": "John",
  "invoice": {
    "series": "INV",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "total": 20,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 5478,
        "name": "Adapter Lenovo",
        "amount": 1,
        "cost": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  "parcels": [
    {
      "quantity": "1",
      "weight": 2000
    }
  ],
  "sender": {
    "company": "string",
    "address": {
      "city": "Tallin",
      "street": "New Street"
    }
  },
  "recipient": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "phone": 30258554455
  }
}';
```

---

```
$arr = json_decode($json_string, true);

var_dump($arr);
```

And if you want to revert is back to a json string, use `json_encode()`

`$json_string = json_encode( $arr );`

json_decode - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

json_encode - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

*note - the json string you provided in your original question was invalid (there's a comma after cost).